# dplyr View() function in r 4.2.1 is behaving differently than previous r version?

Tags: r

I rely quite a bit on `colnames(df) %>% View()` to view colnames or any character vector on top panel of r studio such that I can use the search function to find exact name/value. Before the update, running that line would give me a vertical list of the variables, but after the update to r 4.2.1, I'm getting:

[image]

Thank you for the prompt responses!! My apologies that I do not have sufficient reputation to upvotes these helpful responses.

Here are the updates requested:

@MrFlick yes, indeed, this workaround did the trick, it's strange that this was not necessary before. And yes, indeed seems to be a rstudio problem.

@Ben Bolker here are the info:

```
df <- data.frame(a= seq(1, 10),
                 b= seq(1, 10),
                 c= seq(1, 10),
                 d= seq(1, 10),
                 e= seq(1, 10),
                 f= seq(1, 10),
                 g= seq(1, 10),
                 h= seq(1, 10))

colnames(df) %>% View()
```

> library(magrittr)
> sessionInfo()
> R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
> Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6.4

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjVs8.png) en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjVs8.png) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjVs8.png) magrittr_2.0.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjVs8.png) Rcpp_1.0.8.3        BiocManager_1.30.18 pillar_1.7.0        compiler_4.2.1      forcats_0.5.1       interactions_1.1.5  tools_4.2.1
[8] digest_0.6.29       lubridate_1.8.0     lifecycle_1.0.1     tibble_3.1.7        gtable_0.3.0        pkgconfig_2.0.3     rlang_1.0.3
[15] cli_3.3.0           DBI_1.1.3           rstudioapi_0.13     haven_2.5.0         rJava_1.0-6         stringr_1.4.0       janitor_2.1.0
[22] hablar_0.3.0        dplyr_1.0.9         generics_0.1.3      vctrs_0.4.1         jtools_2.2.0        xlsxjars_0.6.1      hms_1.1.1
[29] grid_4.2.1          tidyselect_1.1.2    snakecase_0.11.0    glue_1.6.2          R6_2.5.1            fansi_1.0.3         tidyr_1.2.0
[36] pander_0.6.5        ggplot2_3.3.6       purrr_0.3.4         scales_1.2.0        ellipsis_0.3.2      assertthat_0.2.1    colorspace_2.0-3
[43] utf8_1.2.2          xlsx_0.6.5          stringi_1.7.6       munsell_0.5.0       crayon_1.5.1

> find("View")
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjVs8.png) "package:utils"

@Rui Barradas, yes, it appears to be a rstudio problem.

Comment: It sounds like you are expecting the data.frame view for a non-data-frame object. Maybe try `colnames(df) %>% as.data.frame() %>% View()`

Comment: can't replicate under "R Under development (unstable) (2022-06-24 r82518)"; `library(magrittr); colnames(mtcars) %>% View(); colnames(as.matrix(mtcars)) %>% View()` both give me vertical lists.  Can we have a [mcve] please, and the results of `sessionInfo()` in a clean (except `magrittr` loaded, or use the base-R `|>` pipe to keep things even cleaner) R session? And results of `find("View")` ?

Comment: I can replicate in RStudio but not in R 4.2.1: `R -q -e "colnames(mtcars) |> View(); Sys.sleep(5)"`.

Comment: I could replicate with R 4.2.0 and RStudio 2022.02.3+492 just using `1:4 |> View()`. It's probably a RStudio thing rather than an R thing.

Comment: On a side note, `View()` is not a function from dplyr. So isn't the title a bit confusing?